# Scala adding elements to seq and handling futures, maps, and async behavior

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm still a newbie in scala and don't quite yet understand the concept of Futures/Maps/Flatmaps/Seq and how to use them properly.

This is what I want to do (pseudo code):

```
 def getContentComponents: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
        contentComponentDTO.list().map( //Future[Seq[ContentComponentModel]] Get all contentComponents
          contentComponents => contentComponents.map( //Iterate over [Seq[ContentComponentModel]
            contentComponent => contentComponent.typeOf match { //Match the type of the contentComponent
              case 1 => contentComponent.pictures :+ contentComponentDTO.getContentComponentPicture(contentComponent.id.get) //Future[Option[ContentComponentPictureModel]] add to _.pictures seq
              case 2 => contentComponent.videos :+ contentComponentDTO.getContentComponentVideo(contentComponent.id.get) //Future[Option[ContentComponentVideoModel]] add to _.videos seq
            }
          )
            Ok(Json.toJson(contentComponents)) //Return all the contentComponents in the end
        )
    }
```

I want to add a `Future[Option[Foo]]` to `contentComponent.pictures: Option[Seq[Foo]]` like so:

```
case 2 => contentComponent.pictures :+ contentComponentDTO.getContentComponentPicture(contentComponent.id.get) //contentComponent.pictures is Option[Seq[Foo]]
```

and return the whole contentComponent back to the front-end via json in the end.

I know this might be far away from the actual code in the end, but I hope you got the idea. Thanks!

Comment: Question is too broad/unclear

Comment: Please do your part of the work too, come up with a much simpler example. This is a very simple question but your example adds lots of irrelevant complexity.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought you might need context. Will edit

Comment: @cchantep Does this help? What would you expect from me? I can't really boil it down more than that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll ignore your code and focus on what is short and makes sense:

> I want to add a Future[Option[Foo]] to contentComponent.pictures: Option[Seq[Foo]] like so:

Let's do this, focusing on code readability:

```
// what you already have
val someFuture: Future[Option[Foo]] = ???
val pics: Option[Seq[Foo]] = contentComponent.pictures
// what I'm adding
val result: Future[Option[Seq[Foo]]] = someFuture.map {
  case None => pics
  case Some(newElement) => 
    pics match {
      case None => Some(Seq(newElement)) // not sure what you want here if pics is empty...
      case Some(picsSequence) => Some(picsSequence :+ newElement)
    }
}
```

And to show an example of `flatMap` let's say you need the result of `result` future in another future, just do:

```
val otherFuture: Future[Any] = ???
val everything: Future[Option[Seq[Foo]]] = otherFuture.flatmap { otherResult =>
  // do something with otherResult i.e., the code above could be pasted in here...
  result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer will attempt to help with some of the conceptual sub-questions which form parts of your overall larger question.

**`flatMap` and `for-yield`**

One of the points of `flatMap` is to help with the problem of the [Pyramid of Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)). This happens when you have
structures nested within structures nested within structures ...

```
doA().map { resultOfA =>
  doB(resultOfA).map { resolutOfB =>
    doC(resultOfB).map { resultOfC =>
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

If you use `for-yield` you get `flatMap` out of the box and it allows you to

> flatten the pyramid

so that your code looks more like a linear structure

```
for {

  resultOfA <- doA
  resultOfB <- doB(resultOfA)
  resultOfC <- doC(resultOfB)
...
} yield {...}
```

There is a rule of thumb in software engineering that deeply nested structures are harder to debug and reason about, so 
we strive to minimise the nesting. You will hit this issue especially when dealing with `Futures`.

**Mapping over `Future` vs. mapping over sequence**

Mapping is usually first thought in terms of iteration over a sequence, which might lead to understanding of 
mapping over a `Future` in terms of *iterating over a sequence of one*. My advice would be not to use the *iteration* concept when
trying to understand mapping over `Futures`, `Options` etc. In these cases it might be better to think of mapping as a process of *destructing the structure*
so that you get at the element inside the structure. One could visualise mapping as

> breaking the shell of a walnut so you get at the delicious kernel inside and then rebuilding the shell.

**`Futures` and monads**

As you try to learn more about `Futures` and when you begin to deal with types like `Future[Option[SomeType]]` you will inevitably 
stumble upon documentation about monads and its cryptic terminology might scare you away. If this happens, it might help to think of monads (of which `Future` is a particular instance) as simply

> something you can stick into a `for-yield` so that you can get at the
>   delicious walnut kernels whilst avoiding the pyramid of doom.